# Naked domain on OpenShift for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dns, openshift

I'm trying to setup a naked domain for my wordpress app on OpenShift. I was able to set this up for my Ghost app on Openshift but the same settings don't seem to work for the current app.

In my DNS settings I have the following:

```
trampkiwpodrozy.com CNAME wordpress-czerwoneczybiale.rhcloud.com
www.trampkiwpodrozy.com CNAME wordpress-czerwoneczybiale.rhcloud.com
```

I also tried this (but without success):

```
*.trampkiwpodrozy.com   CNAME wordpress-czerwoneczybiale.rhcloud.com
```

In OpenShift I added two aliases for my application:

```
 trampkiwpodrozy.com
 www.trampkiwpodrozy.com
```

The domain www.trampkiwpodrozy.com works just fine, however, when I try to access the named domain, ie. trampkiwpodrozy.com I'm getting error about redirection loop.

To reply to one of the comments, this is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Uncomment the following lines to force HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# WordPress Defaults
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: What do you have set for your site url in your wordpress admin settings?

Comment: I set www.trampkiwpodrozy.com. I tried setting there trampkiwpodrozy.com but this caused a problem because I couldn't even access the admin part of the blog (because trampkiwpodrozy.com could not be loaded due to redirect ion loops).

Comment: paste the .htaccess inside .openshift/config directory here, it's a rewrite issue!

Comment: you mean ssh to openshift server and find the config/.htaccess file?

Comment: do you have your local git repository? if not, then you need to find it in your website doc root.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to have naked domain serve on your website address, just use ONE alias with naked domain on openshift, then use DNS CNAME to forward your www. to the naked domain to avoid the loop.

```
trampkiwpodrozy.com CNAME wordpress-czerwoneczybiale.rhcloud.com
www.trampkiwpodrozy.com CNAME trampkiwpodrozy.com
```

Comment: OK, so now I have just trampkiwpodrozy.com  setup as an alias in OpenShift. In my domain settings I have trampkiwpodrozy.com pointing to wordpress-czerwoneczybiale.rhcloud.com and www.trampkiwpodrozy.com pointing to trampkiwpodrozy.com. What happens when I try to reach trampkiwpodrozy.com I'm getting redirected to https://www.trampkiwpodrozy.com/app and I see error message: "The requested URL /app was not found on this server."

Comment: in your openshift account's domain alias, make sure you only have trampkiwpodrozy.com as your app's alias, not www.trampkiwpodrozy.com!

Comment: yes, this is what I have - only one alias in openshift web console and the alias is trampkiwpodrozy.com

Comment: did you installed any redirect plugin in your wordpress?

Comment: Nope, but my wordpress has www.trampkiwpodrozy.com setup as a domain.

Comment: it's a redirect issue, when i hit trampkiwpodrozy.com, it goes to your ip address 52.2.21.17, but it redirect with 301 to www.trampkiwpodrozy.com, then redirect with 302 to https www.trampkiwpodrozy.com/app, of course when i direct hit your server with www.trampkiwpodrozy.com then it redirect with 302 to https www.trampkiwpodrozy.com/app, i just don't know where you could insert your redirect, did you setup your project with wordpress quickstart or something else? could you repost your .htaccess file under your server's app-deployments/current/repo directory?

Comment: Yeah, I also don't understand the redirection to /app. Yes, I used wordpress quickstart. I added the content of .htaccess to my original question. Thanks for your patience with helping me with this.

Comment: try remove all alias from openshift, then recreate the alias, seems openshift had this problem internally, https://forums.openshift.com/again-aliases-are-redirecting-and-app-get-404-error

Comment: Yes, I've tried this many times already. But done that one more time to make sure - deleting alias from openshift (so no alias defined after this), add one alias to trampkiwpodrozy.com. The outcome is that it still redirects to /app.
Funny thing is that I had a nodejs app before on openshift and I had domain at the same provider and I was able to setup my naked domain and www without big problems with the settings from my original post.

Comment: then delete the whole app and recreate it, use rhc.